# Ignite throwing Failed to wait for partition map exchange - Dataset.write()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

using Ignite2.8 with Spark2.3 Using persistence Cache.
Writing different Spark Data sets into Ignite Cache with different name of table using below code.  The first two Data sets write in Ignite Cache is successful and then Ignite is giving warning and its hanging there

```
rankDS.write().format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE())
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) //Overwriting entire table.
.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), CONFIG)
.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE(), "myrank")
.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS(), "plan_cd")
.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS(), "template=replicated")
//.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_STREAMER_ALLOW_OVERWRITE(), true)
.save();

[2020-03-25 20:17:25,011][WARN ][exchange-worker-#46][diagnostic] Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=6], node=4ad0efe1-032e-4584-b3de-09d1cf9b5f25]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause: 
[2020-03-25 20:17:25,011][WARN ][exchange-worker-#46][diagnostic] Ready affinity version: AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=5]
[2020-03-25 20:17:25,011][WARN ][exchange-worker-#46][diagnostic] Last exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=DynamicCacheChangeBatch [id=1b891341171-a48142d4-6ce3-4eea-a193-103f849d0cb4, reqs=ArrayList [DynamicCacheChangeRequest [cacheName=SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK, hasCfg=true, nodeId=4ad0efe1-032e-4584-b3de-09d1cf9b5f25, clientStartOnly=false, stop=false, destroy=false, disabledAfterStartfalse]], exchangeActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=[SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK], stopCaches=null, startGrps=[SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], startCaches=false], affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=6], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4ad0efe1-032e-4584-b3de-09d1cf9b5f25, consistentId=5fa08415-00d8-44ba-a105-ad349e4ab16a, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.10.26.7, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [BPFD6F4B482.1199nbf.net/10.10.26.7:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1585181732934, loc=true, ver=2.8.0#20200226-sha1:341b01df, isClient=false], topVer=1, nodeId8=4ad0efe1, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1585181824935]], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4ad0efe1-032e-4584-b3de-09d1cf9b5f25, consistentId=5fa08415-00d8-44ba-a105-ad349e4ab16a, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.10.26.7, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [BPFD6F4B482.1199nbf.net/10.10.26.7:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1585181732934, loc=true, ver=2.8.0#20200226-sha1:341b01df, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=6], discoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=DynamicCacheChangeBatch [id=1b891341171-a48142d4-6ce3-4eea-a193-103f849d0cb4, reqs=ArrayList [DynamicCacheChangeRequest [cacheName=SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK, hasCfg=true, nodeId=4ad0efe1-032e-4584-b3de-09d1cf9b5f25, clientStartOnly=false, stop=false, destroy=false, disabledAfterStartfalse]], exchangeActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=[SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK], stopCaches=null, startGrps=[SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], startCaches=false], affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=6], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4ad0efe1-032e-4584-b3de-09d1cf9b5f25, consistentId=5fa08415-00d8-44ba-a105-ad349e4ab16a, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.10.26.7, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [BPFD6F4B482.1199nbf.net/10.10.26.7:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1585181732934, loc=true, ver=2.8.0#20200226-sha1:341b01df, isClient=false], topVer=1, nodeId8=4ad0efe1, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1585181824935]], nodeId=4ad0efe1, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT], added=true, exchangeType=CLIENT, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=true, hash=939773374], init=true, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=[SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK], stopCaches=null, startGrps=[SQL_PUBLIC_MYRANK], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], affChangeMsg=null, centralizedAff=false, forceAffReassignment=false, exchangeLocE=null, cacheChangeFailureMsgSent=false, done=false, state=CRD, registerCachesFuture=GridFinishedFuture [resFlag=2], partitionsSent=false, partitionsReceived=false, delayedLatestMsg=null, afterLsnrCompleteFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1630530008], timeBag=o.a.i.i.util.TimeBag@7971cf91, startTime=853079188170762, initTime=1585181824939, rebalanced=false, evtLatch=0, remaining=HashSet [], mergedJoinExchMsgs=null, awaitMergedMsgs=0, super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1775793556]]
[2020-03-25 20:17:25,011][WARN ][exchange-worker-#46][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] First 10 pending exchange futures [total=0]
[2020-03-25 20:17:25,012][WARN ][exchange-worker-#46][diagnostic] Last 10 exchange futures (total: 6):
```

Comment: Unfortunately, complete logs from all server nodes is required to make sense of this. Can you upload and share those?

Comment: Thanks for response!! its a single node only. We are creating one dataset for each source table and writing to Ignite cache so that we can join them before loading final result set into Mongo DB.  The data volume is about 20 Million Records. Shall we just use spark for extracts and do joins and business logic in Mongo Aggregate Query? I will send log file of single node.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no Spark expertise, I suggest asking another question about that.